# How can i update my OS (gingerbread)

Tags: updates, samsung, operating-system

This question may be very low quality but it is very important for me ..I have Samsung
galaxy-Pro and the Os version is `Android OS, v2.2.2 (Froyo)`.

The question is that i want to update it to gingerbread and there is no software update button in `foryo`.

There are many articles like using `ODIN...`.Is that safe or is there any other official way to update that(like google)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to use ODIN. I've done it myself, and it worked for me. I used it to root my phone (SGS2). I've postponed it for months, afraid it would brick my phone, but it didn't.

- Make a backup of all important data.
- Find a good manual on Youtube, XDA-developers or via Google. Compare them, and see what they say.
- Be prepared that it can go wrong. If it goes wrong, it could mean that your phone is bricked.

I have a friend who bricked his Samsung phone, and Samsung repaired it without making problems over a rooted phone.

Google won't update your phone. Samsung has to prepare an update because of phone specific drivers and their own specific apps. That's the only official way to update, and if Samsung doesn't make that update, there is no alternative but to use a ROM.